# How to call a specific return of a function in Python?

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to write a numerical integration code. I have a function `GetAcc`, and it returns two acceleration values which are x and y compononets. How can I call first and second return values at the different parts?

This is my function.

```
def GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions):
    global xAcc
    global yAcc
    xAcc = np.zeros(xPositions.size, xPositions.size)
    yAcc = np.zeros(yPositions.size, yPositions.size)

    for i in range(0, xPositions.size-1):
        for j in range(i+1, xPositions.size):
            r_x = xPositions[j] - xPositions[i]
            r_y = yPositions[j] - yPositions[i]

            rmag = np.sqrt(r_x*r_x + r_y*r_y)

            force_scalar = GetLJForce(rmag, 0.84, 2.56)
            
            force_x = force_scalar * r_x / rmag
            force_y = force_scalar * r_y / rmag

            xAcc[i,j] = force_x / m
            xAcc[j,i] = - force_x / m
            
            yAcc[i,j] = force_y / m
            yAcc[j,i] = - force_y / m

    return np.sum(xAcc, axis=0), np.sum(yAcc, axis=0)
```

Since I couldn't find a solution, I tried this:

```
def GetxAcc(xPositions):
    a, b = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)

    return a

def GetyAcc(xPositions):
    a, b = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)

    return b
```

And I need to call the x-component which is `np.sum(xAcc, axis=0)` here.

```
def RunMDx(dt, number_of_steps, x):
    global xPositions
    xPositions = np.zeros((number_of_steps, 3))

    v_x = 0
    a_x = GetxAcc(x)

    for i in range(number_of_steps):
        x = UpdatexPos(x, v_x, a_x, dt)
        a1_x = GetxAcc(x)
        v_x = UpdatexVel(v_x, a_x, a1_x, dt)
        a_x = np.array(a1_x)

        xPositions[i, :] = x

    return xPositions
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can always choose to use only the required value right.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. But I need help at that moment.

Comment: define a class and set `self.a, self.b = GetAcc(....)` then use `self.a` and `self.b` everywhere you need

Comment: What @Sreekiran meant, I think, is after `a, b = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)` you can just use a or b, whichever you need at the time. If you're worried about creating unnecessary variables, as far as I know, in Python you can name a variable _ and Python understands it's not meant to be used, sort of a throw-away variable (e.g. `a, _ = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)`)

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli, how can I call it?

Comment: @dm2 when I try similar way, it returns that yPositions is not defined.

Comment: @dm2 in addition, I need to use the second return at the next step.

Comment: @dm2 `_` is just a valid variable name, the convention is to use it as a dummy variable and only use on the left side of a `=` or as a for loop variable, but you can use it as any other variable

Comment: What does `GetAcc` return? A **TUPLE**. so use it as a tuple

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
a_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
```

Comment: I got this message.                                                                                                 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "md2.py", line 91, in <module>
    sim_xpos = RunMDx(0.1, 1000, x)
  File "md2.py", line 59, in RunMDx
    a_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
  File "md2.py", line 17, in GetAcc
    xAcc = np.zeros(xPositions.size, xPositions.size)
TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: That must be some other error then. If a function returns two values, they are returned as a tuple, the values of which can be accessed with this [0] thing (sorry, don't know how it's called..)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see your example.

Comment: yeah, I'm new to Stackexchange, wanted to make a paragraph, not post the comment.. I edited the comment now.